# How to programmatically add a new line into an WPF Textbox using PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, textbox, newline

I am simple windows admin who is trying to create a simple WPF form with a textbox and a button control. Basically, when I press the button I would like to write to the textbox line after another. It seems easy enough in all other programming languages to add a new line if you use \n or \r in your String but I am struggling to do this using PowerShell in WPF. Will you be able to guide me please?

```
$button.add_Click({

$OutputBox.AppendText( "`r`n")
$OutputBox.Text = "Complete1"
$OutputBox.AppendText("`r`n")
$OutputBox.Text = "Complete2"
$OutputBox.AppendText("`r`n")
$OutputBox.Text = "Complete3"

})
```

And I tried this way as well

```
$button.add_Click({

$OutputBox.Text = "Complete1`r`n"
$OutputBox.Text = "Complete2`r`n"
$OutputBox.Text = "Complete3`r`n"

})
```

The XAML code for the textbox is written like this

```
<TextBox Name="OutputBox" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135" Margin="88,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="....." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430"/>
```

The expected output is like this

```
Complete1
Complete2
Complete3
```

Instead it only gives out

```
Complete3
```

Comment: Use only AppendText instead of replacing the whole text by assigning a new value to the Text property: `$OutputBox.AppendText("Complete2\`r\`n")`

Comment: @Clemens - Wow I completely messed that up, that worked like a charm, post it as an answer.